# Show if $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ then $\int_{\Bbb{R}} \vert f \vert \chi_{\{x \in \Bbb{R}: \vert f(x) \vert > n\}} dm=0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

So let $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ and show

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Bbb{R}} \vert f \vert \chi_{\{x \in \Bbb{R}: \vert f(x) \vert > n\}} dm = 0$$

Is this because $\int_{\Bbb{R}} \vert f \vert dm < \infty$ thus for large $n$, $\chi$ is zero? any $\textbf{Hints}$ greatly appreciated. Not full on solutions. Should I define a sequence of measurable functions

$$f_n(x):=f \cdot\chi(x)$$

which is integrable since $f$ is integrable. Then show the integral of these goes to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Aha bound it above by an integrable function that tends to zero? @geetha290krm

Comment: what can I bound it above by though? since my $\chi$ is all value $x$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert > n$.

Comment: The integrand is bounded by $|f|$ tends to  pointwise.

Comment: but how to we know $\int \vert f \vert = 0$ @geetha290krm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint is to actually define measurable sets:
$$A_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: |f(x)| \geq n \}$$
I'll let you think about why this is a measurable set. How does $A_{n+1}$ relate to $A_n$? Then, define as sequence of non-negative functions:
$$f_n = |f| \chi_{A_n}$$
What is the point-wise limit of this sequence of functions? How does $f_{n+1}$ relate to $f_n$? Use what you determined about the sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$!

**Full Solution Ahead, Do Not Read Initially**

Define $A_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: |f(x)| \geq n \}$. Observe that $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$. In particular, $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence of sets. In particular, if we define a sequence of functions:
$$f_n = |f|\chi_{A_n}$$

then it follows that $f_{n+1} \leq f_n$. Next, let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $n > |f(x)|$. This implies that for all $n \geq N$, $x \notin A_n$. That is, $f_n(x) = 0$ when $n \geq N$. Hence, $f_n(x) \to 0$. By the Monotone Convergence Theorem:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x) \ dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 0 \ dx = 0$$
as was desired.

Comment: Question, how is it by MCT when the $f_n$ are decreasing? doesn't MCT assume the sequence of nonnegative measurable functions be increasing? OR can MCT be applied to increasing or decreasing sequence of nonnegative measurable functions?